# How to solve $y''+y'\cot x+\frac M{\cot x}y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good afternoon. I was wondering how can I solve
$$y''+y'\cot x+\frac M{\cot x}y=0$$
for $M$ constant and $y$ a function of $x$?

I also want to ask what to call these kinds of equations where the coefficients are also functions of $x$.

Comment: In terms of classification this is a linear (only depends on $y$ and its derivatives linearly), homogeneous (all terms depend on $y$ or one of its derivatives) differential equation with nonconstant coefficients (coefficients are functions of $x$ as you stated).

Answer (score 2):

Maple finds a rather complicated solution in terms of Heun functions:
$$
y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\, \left( \cot \left( x \right) +i
 \right) ^{1/4-i/4\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}} \left( \cot \left( x \right) -i
 \right) ^{-1/4\,{\frac {-\sqrt {4\,iM-1}+4\,M+i}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}}}{
\it HeunG} \left( 2,1/8\,{\frac { \left( 4\,iM-2\,i\sqrt {4\,iM-1}-1
 \right) \sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+8\,iM\sqrt {4\,iM-1}-2\,i-8\,M+3\,\sqrt {4\,
iM-1}}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}},i/4\sqrt {4\,iM-1}-i/4\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+1/2,-1
/4\,{\frac {4\,M+i\sqrt {4\,iM-1}\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+i-2\,\sqrt {4\,iM-1}
}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}},-i/2\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+1,0,1-i\cot \left( x \right) 
 \right) +{\it \_C2}\, \left( \cot \left( x \right) +i \right) ^{1/4+i
/4\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}} \left( \cot \left( x \right) -i \right) ^{-1/4\,{
\frac {-\sqrt {4\,iM-1}+4\,M+i}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}}}{\it HeunG} \left( 2
,1/8\,{\frac {8\,iM\sqrt {4\,iM-1}-4\,iM\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+2\,i\sqrt {4
\,iM-1}\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}-8\,M+3\,\sqrt {4\,iM-1}+\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}-2\,i
}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}},i/4 \left( -2\,i+\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+\sqrt {4\,iM-1}
 \right) ,-1/4\,{\frac {4\,M-i\sqrt {4\,iM-1}\sqrt {-1-4\,iM}+i-2\,
\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}{\sqrt {4\,iM-1}}},1+i/2\sqrt {-1-4\,iM},0,1-i\cot
 \left( x \right)  \right) 
$$

Perhaps you'd prefer series solutions?

There is a [regular singular point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) at $x=0$ with indicial equation $r^2 = 0$.
Thus there should be a solution $y_1$ of the form

$$y_1 = 1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ldots$$

Take as many terms as you wish.
Plugging this in to the d.e. and taking the first few terms of the series around $x=0$ we get

$$ \dfrac{a_1}{x} + 4 a_2 + \left(9 a_3 - \dfrac{a_1}{3} + M\right) x + \ldots = 0$$

The coefficient of each power of $x$ must be $0$, so $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 0$, 
$a_3 = -M/9$.

A second fundamental solution will be of the form

$$ y_2(x) = y_1(x) \log(x) + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + \ldots$$

Again plug it in and take the first few terms of the series: note that the 
part where you don't differentiate the log should be $0$ because $y_1$ is a solution.

$$ \dfrac{b_1}{x} + 4 b_2 - \dfrac{1}{3} + \left(-\dfrac{2M}{3} - \dfrac{b_1}{3} + 9 b_3\right) x + \ldots = 0$$

so that $b_1 = 0$, $b_2 =  1/12$, $b_3 = 2M/27$.

EDIT: Since $\cot$ is not a rational function, and its Laurent series doesn't even have a closed form, this approach can determine the coefficients individually but not in closed form, and doesn't even give a recurrence for them.

On the other hand, the change of independent variable $\cot(x) = t$ gives $y(x) = Y(t)$ with

$$ t (t^2+1) Y''(t) + t^2 (t^2+1) Y'(t) + M Y(t) = 0$$

Here there is a regular singular point at $t=0$ with indicial equation 
$r^2-r = 0$.  The solution corresponding to indicial root $1$ is then

$$ Y_1(t) = t - \dfrac{M}{2} t^2 + \left(\frac{M^2}{12}-\frac{1}{6}\right) t^3 + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n t^n$$

where $a_n$ satisfy the recurrence

$$ n^2 a_n + (n+2)(2n+3) a_{n+2} + M a_{n+3} + (n+4)(n+3) a_{n+4} = 0$$

Comment: Robert, could you guide me through you7r series solution approach?
Would be so thankful

Comment: Thank you very much Robert for your help. 
I have a couple of technical questions and I apologize in advance if they sound naive:
1- Why is the indicial equation $r^2=0$? I would get M=0 to be honest for x=0
2- How did you choose y1 and y2 the fundamental solutions? How would approach that? Is it a standard method or just trial and error approach?
3- In the series solution approach, the change of independent variable $cot(x)=t$ where did $t^2 +1$ come from? 
Thank you
Thank you very much

Comment: See [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: As for the change of variables, it's basically the Chain Rule.  If $y(x) = Y(t)$, $$\dfrac{dY}{dt} =\dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dt},\ \dfrac{d^2 Y}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} \left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$$
where $x = \text{arccot}(t)$ so $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$$